# BIDS 2008 - Create multiple dimensions from DataSource View

Tags: ssas, bids, olap-cube, ssas-2008

A while back I created a cube in BIDS 2008 (no R2) with a single facts table and around 28 dimensions. This got deployed to SQL 2008 and auto-updates itself with data from the ERP system (using a data-warehouse and SSIS and all that).

The customer liked it and wanted me to make another one.

The next one, however, has around a 100 dimension views in SQL.

I created the Datasource view (looks enormous) but is there some way to automate creating the dimensions based on the DataSource View tables?

My sanity is at stake here :-).

**EDIT:**

I did it manually for the moment, but I'd still like a method for possible future cubes.

Comment: Do you really need that many dimensions? Most cubes have between three and twenty. Maybe you can (e. g. via views or Named Query in the DSV) combine several dimension tables to one. Analysis Services works fine with dimension tables e. g. having 50 or 100 attribute columns.

Comment: @FrankPI: I'm sure a dozen or so dimensions can be logically combined into two or three dimensions (Account Number, Account Description, Account Group Code, Account Category... can be combined in Account with x attributes). I'll still end up with a lot of dimensions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Within BIDS, the only automation would be this: If you create a cube using the wizard, all the dimension objects that you configure will be created for you, as long as the dimension does not yet exist. However, these automatically created dimensions just have the key attribute. You will have to add all other attributes for each dimension manually.

Comment: This might be interesting... I'll mark it as the answer for now.